# Can YUIs DataTable do inline cell editing with auto completion?

Tags: javascript, yui

I'm trying to get [YUIs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) [DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) to work using [Inline Cell Editing](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_cellediting.html) that can [Auto Complete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/).

In this thread:

http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui2/ticket/2528064

Somebody provides a non-working solution, that seems close.

Has anybody tried to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:
http://gist.github.com/406977

Let me know if you run into any problems.